# javascript masonry not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

Hello all i have a problem with javascript masonry here is the code this is just a test piece please help me....

i have tried this code but this is not working please help me ..
thanks in advance..

any help is appreciated...

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js">    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/master/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var $container = $('.portfolio-container');
  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.break',
      columnWidth : 129
  });
});

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
 .break {
 float: left;
 width: 129px;
 margin: 3px;
background-color:blue;

 }
 .break1{height:30px;}
 .break2{height:50px;}
 .break3{height:20px;}
 .break4{height:70px;}
 </style>

 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="portfolio-container">

 <?php 
        for ($i=1; $i<9; $i++){
        ?>
            <div class="break1 break" >

            </div><div class="break2 break" >

            </div><div class="break3 break">

            </div><div class="break4 break" >

            </div>
        <?php } ?>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the code AND just a test piece. Where is the real thing ?

Comment: Where is the js tag `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both paths/urls you have used (*for the masonry and imageloaded plugins*) are wrong..

Use the urls from a CDN if you want

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.1/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.0.4/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
```

or download those files and link to them.

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/C2mCw/1/

---

Besides the wrong urls, the `columnWidth` option you use must take into account the full width of each element (*including paddings/margins*).

So, since you have a `margin:3px` on the `.break` items, you will have to account for 6 extra pixels

so you should really set it to 135 instead of 129

```
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.break',
    columnWidth : 135
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/C2mCw/2/